# How do I fix GUI Miner stuck at connecting?

Tags: mac, windows, stratum, guiminer, miner-configuration

GUI Miner v2011-08-24 just shows "connecting..." when trying to connect to slush's pool. The console shows:

```
2011-12-31 14:00:49: Running command: poclbm.exe smithd98@gmail.com.macbookpro:4fuqPtrI@api2.bitcoin.cz:8332 --device=0 --platform=0 --verbose 
2011-12-31 14:00:49: Listener for "Default" started
2011-12-31 14:06:53: Listener for "Default": api2.bitcoin.cz:8332 31/12/2011 14:06:53, long poll: new block 0000028fd540f91b
2011-12-31 14:07:33: Listener for "Default": api2.bitcoin.cz:8332 31/12/2011 14:07:33, long poll: new block 0000079641b6608b
```

where xxxxxx is my correct password.

I've tried uninstalling (removing the directory, ensuring the process isn't running, and unzipping again) as suggested in this post: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=printpage;topic=28886.0 but it hasn't worked.

Comment: You forgot to censor you password and nothing looks wrong with this console output. Are you sure it isn't just working?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is working. From my research this doesn't look like correct output, but I'm not sure. I gave up trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

you're using api2.bitcoincz.com:8332 but that's not listed on the pool's site:

Run your own GPU/FPGA/ASIC miner with the worker credentials you gave earlier, and connect it to following URL:

http://api.bitcoin.cz:8332
(Main pool URL)

or
stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333
(If you have Stratum-compatible miner)

Comment: @DavidSilvaSmith: That is not how StackExchange works. If this is the correct answer, you should mark it as such.

Comment: Sorry I meant I have no way to test the answer to determine if it is correct. I should probably delete my question since it is old.